# In Lua Hammerspoon script, how to draw on a specific desktop?

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I don't see any APIs to enumarate desktops or move drawing to a specific desktop.

Comment: What do you mean draw on a specific desktop exactly?

Comment: I mean, I have 6 desktops, and I want to draw on a specific one, and not on the current one. specifically I want to draw some different text on each desktop

Comment: Using `hs.drawing` or whatever? Aren't those just windows that exist on a given space? Are you trying to target a new window to some other non-active desktop?

Comment: indeed I am using `hs.drawing`. and I suppose those are just windows. but a) I don't see a way to get the window out of a drawing, and  b) I don't see a  way to move a window to specific desktop

Comment: Yeah, hammerspoon doesn't really deal with spaces yet. There's [this "experimental" module](https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.undocumented.spaces) that you can try to use (and other people have if you look around) that might be of use to you here.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation always names THE desktop and desktop does not have any window id nor subrole I assume Hammerspoon does not support multiple desktops?

Hammerspoon seems to treat desktop as one of a kind top level window object.